# How to avoid libpciaccess initialization error with mpiexec

Tags: mpi, freebsd

mpiexec causes the following error with mpich-3.4.1 or openmpi-4.4.1 on FreeBSD.

```
PCI: Failed to initialize libpciaccess with pci_system_init(): 6 (Permission denied)
```

The following test program

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(void) {
  int pcidev = open( "/dev/pci", O_RDWR | O_CLOEXEC );
  printf("pcidev=%d\n", pcidev);
  return 0;
}
```

indeed fails without administrator privilege.

```
% ./a.out
pcidev=-1
% sudo ./a.out
Password:
pcidev=3
```

The error is not critical, but it would be nice if we could get rid of it.

Comment: Both MPICH and Open MPI use `hwloc` under the hood (and `hwloc` in turn uses `libpciaccess`) so I guess the error is caused by a dependency rather than the MPI library itself. At the user level, an option would be to direct `hwloc` to use the topology provided by the user (via a `xml` file, generated by the sysadmin here) instead of trying to retrieve it from the kernel.

Comment: Thank you. I'll take a look at `hwloc`.

Comment: According to hwloc [issue 456](https://github.com/open-mpi/hwloc/issues/456), it is a know limitation of BSD and the error message will be hidden as of 2.5. A workaround is presented in the issue.